# Connection pooling to simplify In memory DB testing + which pool library

Tags: spring, testing, connection, pool

I'm working on a project that includes multiple maven modules (Domain, API and Client)
The API is dependant only on the domain and the Client is only Dependent on the API
I also have 2 tomcat servers (development and release). Now I'm having a hard time to always change the connection string manually when I need to deploy to the relase. Now I've heard from Connection pooling (DBCP, C3PO and a new one HikariCP) so I'm looking in to that to bring in use.

Now I also heard Spring framework can help me via Dependency injection to help configure Datasources.

The questions :
Which of the above (Spring or pure connection pool libraries or both) should I use?

Also keep in mind that I want to facilitate testing by an in-memory data store (HSQLDB)
I could have a configuration file just for holding the config of the connection to the MySQL server (localhost or release)

How can I use DBUnit testing interchangeably between the in memory DB (HSQLDB) and my local MySQL server?

EDIT: FORGET THIS

EDIT2:

Now I have this in my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:datasource.properties" />
</bean> 

<bean id="parentDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="minimumPoolSize" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="developmentDataSource" parent="parentDataSource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
            <constructor-arg>
                <props>
                    <prop key="dataSource.url">${dev.url}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.user">${dev.user}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.password">${dev.password}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.portNumber">${dev.portNumber}</prop>
                </props>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="releaseDataSource" parent="parentDataSource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
            <constructor-arg>
                <props>
                    <prop key="dataSource.url">${release.url}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.user">${release.user}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.password">${release.password}</prop>
                    <prop key="dataSource.portNumber">${release.portNumber}</prop>
                </props>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I get an error if I define the dataSourceClassName property in the parent bean
Also I can't use the destroy-method on the parent bean (I don't know if I'll need it)

Anything you can add to make this more to better use

Now I can just add my HSQLDB in memory DB to the list for testing purposes?

Comment: Destroying the DataSource/pool is generally a good idea if the application is running in an environment where it can be hot deployed or restarted without shutting down the container.  In that case, failure to call the shutdown() can lead to memory leaks by not allowing the classes loaded by the context ClassLoader to be garbage collected.  But if the container shuts down along with your application, it is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the developers of [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).  Almost any of the connection pools should allow you to do what you are trying to do.  You simply need the connection and pool configuration in a properties file, one for each database, and a way to swap them -- possibly via a system property.  For example:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(System.getProperty("db.propfile"));
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

And then simply launching with `-Ddb.propfile=mysql.properties` or `-Ddb.propfile=hsqldb.properties`.  Alternatively, you could use something like Spring, though making the Spring configuration dynamic could be trickier -- unless you swap out the Spring configuration files in a similar way.

EDIT: If you run with MySQL in production and HSQLDB in test, you can even make the system property default to the MySQL configuration so if the `db.propfile` property is not specified it uses that:

```
System.getProperty("db.propfile", "mysql.properties")
```

If you're deployed in a WAR, you might need to make the path relative.  For example, relative to WEB-INF:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("./WEB-INF/" + System.getProperty("db.propfile"));
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but where do you place the db.propfile? System.getProperty is always getting a null value (I'm just testing this out in a simple maven application) I've set it at the root of the application but it's not finding it.

Comment: If ``System.getProperty("db.propfile")`` is returning null, then it is not being passed properly when the application is started.  Normal Java invocation would be something like ``java -Ddb.propfile=mysql.properties -jar application.jar``.  Are you using a maven plugin like the dbunit plugin to execute the tests?  In which case, you might check to see if it accepts system properties like the [surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).